# How to forcibly delete or close opened file?

Tags: windows, file-management, samba, file-permissions, file-descriptors

Theoretical question. I have a network with 2 PC, running Windows. One PC is sharing a samba folder with video file, and i've opened up that file on second PC and started streaming video in infinite loop, so it will never close that file. Then i tried to delete a file from first PC. It denies deletion and says that file is opened. How can i forcibly delete that file?

- not touching second PC, it will never close file
- within current Windows Session (no reboot/poweroff)
- not unplugging ethernet cable

Comment: Can [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) deal with this?

Comment: When you say "samba", do you literally mean [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) (the Linux/Unix SMB server), or do you mean the [SMB protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233(v=vs.85).aspx) in general?

Comment: @xakepp35 - I took your comment to indicate you were actually talking about the Brazillian genre.  Grawity comment isn't considered trolling.  *Please be respectful of all users.*  You also didn't answer his question, which is a shame, because you should have.

Comment: @xakepp35 - In the future just answer the question, posed by people, seeking clarification.

Comment: The information requested wasn't unnecessary and was 100% related to answering your question.

Comment: @Ramhound To clarify, i would say "how to close opened descriptor?". He answered for original question in title - `net file` or `psfile`. Files opened by incoming connections could be closed from `fsmgmt.msc`. Question is closed. I like to chat, but its now pointless debate.

Comment: I am trying to help you, so in the future, you are not suspended for being rude to other users.  You were disrespectful to Grawity, you seem to think his question about Samba vs SMB wasn't relevant and unnecessary, except it was both necessary and relevant. I am trying to let you know, so you don't make the same mistake, in the future.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help, i appreciated it very much and understand your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. On the host computer, open **Computer Management** using an account with administrator permissions. *(search for "compmgmt.msc" in the start menu and right-click, Run as Administrator"*)
2. Expand **Shared Folders** and **Open Files**.
3. Find the open file you wish to delete, right-click on it and select **Close Open File**.

Comment: I'd just say `fsmgmt.msc` for the 1st step. Also command-line `net file` and SysInternals' `psfile`.

Comment: Windows+X, G on  win2016 system. Thanks a lot, it worked! :)

Comment: @grawity Thanks for useful command line hints :)